# Как отправить ответ на ответ из списка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Проблема в том ,что бот не откликается на команду. Скорее всего дело в том, что я сравниваю строку со списком. Как исправить?

```
hi_words = ["Привет", "привет", "Хай"]


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def on_message(message):
    if message.text is hi_words:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй `in`

```
if message.text in hi_words:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет")
```

Answer (score -1):

В данном коде вы сравниваете `message.text` со списком `hi_words`. Через `is` можно сравнивать, но А) Не в этом случае; Б) Это не совсем корректно и вызывает синтаксическое предупреждение: `SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?`, что не очень приятно. Вам же нужно использовать `is in`. Готовый код:

```
hi_words = ["Привет", "привет", "Хай"]


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda m: True)
def on_message(message):
    if message.text is in hi_words:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет")
```

Comment: В python нет конструкции `is in`, подобный код вызовет ошибку `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`: https://ideone.com/tDBSee. Для проверки наличия элемента в списке нужно использовать просто in.